# Best way to check for Memory LEAKS on POSIX THREAD's STACK?

Tags: c

I have used Totalview's Memoryscape to do some memory leaks checks and I have "none", well at least none on the HEAP....but it seems tools like MemoryScape only check the heap, not stack leaks...

I have noticed a small leak occurring on AIX and Solaris (any maybe Linux, still checking)....and am trying to hunt it down.

I do use a single (joinable) thread in my application that does all the work...

Please bear with me, C is not my day job ;-) but I have 2 questions:

- If I spawn an POSIX thread and it does malloc's etc...are these on the heap or on the threads stack? Would a memory checking (heap) tool typically also find leaks when a thread does not free a malloc?
- What tools would you recommend to use to find leaks on the STACK? I have used "libumem" on Solaris but not sure if that is finding what I need..

Can I perhaps use VALGRIND on Linux to check for leaks on my thread's stack?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Comment: Unless he means he mallocs the space he is using for the thread's stack.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was meaning "stack memory"....the tools I use seem to only look at heap memory not stack memory from threads...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I spawn an POSIX thread and it does malloc's etc...are these on the
>   heap or on the threads stack? Would a memory checking (heap) tool
>   typically also find leaks when a thread does not free a malloc?

Everything you get via `malloc`, no matter where you call it is from the heap. A memory debugger should be able to catch leaks. Valgrind is a good tool to find leaks, it should work well with threads.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a "leak" on the stack. The technical term for local variables are "automatic variables" and they are deallocated as soon as the function exits.

But you CAN have a leak if you have a joinable thread, but do not explicitly call `pthread_join()` on the thread handle.

Comment: Hi there, I have done a pthread_join() on the thread handle...I guess I am confused why my application seems to be leaking even though libumem and TotalView's MemoryScape say nothing...mmmm